# For loop equivalent for dataFrame columns in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Is there a way for me to iterate through each column via a For-loop?

My data is loaded into a dataFrame, but beyond explicitly naming a specific pair of columns, I am having a hard time doing generalized iterations over the columns to perform comparisons.

Ideally I'd be able to do simple computations (in an iterative manner) like so:

```
for columns in df:
    if(df[column] > df[column+1]):
        return True
```

Where my data looks like:

```
S1 S2 S3 C1  C2  C3  conclusion
1  10 23 200 180 125 "black"
6  18 34 200 221 230 "red"
4  21 32 200 150 250 "orange"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to iterate through all the columns in the data frame? `df.columns` will give you an array of the columns in the data frame
Use

```
for column in df.columns:
    print(df[column])
```

If you want to compare one column with immediate next column, use

```
column_array=df.columns.tolist()
for column,next_column in zip(df.columns,column_array[1:]):
    if (df[column] > df[next_column]):
        return true
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to iterate through the columns, depending on what you would like to do

By using the column label:

```
for column in df.columns:
    df[column]
```

By using the numeric index:

```
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    df.iloc[:, i]
```

With `iteritems`:

```
for name, column in df.iteritems():
    column
```

I'm unsure of what the output of `if(df[column] > df[column+1]):` should be because you have both strings and ints in your dataframe, however one of the above methods should be able to be adapted for what you need